# Does Ethereum 2.0 still have a gas cost?

Tags: gas, eth-2.0

I read various articles about this. Some said there is no gas cost, some said there was, some said the whole question was in transition until 2021.

Has anyone the official statement about gas costs and Ethereum 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All blockchains have transaction fees, as otherwise there is no way to secure the network.

Comment: PoA networks have no fees, and nor do blockchains under Hyperledger Fabric.

Comment: They still have indirect fees, as node operators need to be compensated somehow. There are no free lunches.

Comment: These are not fees, they are costs.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the first answer, fees are essential. They prevent DDOS attacks on the blockchain and pay the miners (in addition to the block reward).

I think you refer to the transaction pricing model. Ethereum 1.0 will likely revise it with the EIP-1559 (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md).

The current fee system is auction-based and has some limitations.
The EIP will introduce a base fee per gas adjusted for each block by the protocol depending on the network congestion (in the same way that the mining difficulty changes depending on the total hash rate). Moreover, the block gas limit will not be anymore fixed but dynamic. Users will always have to set a tip, called gas premium, in addition to the base fee. As the base fee is burnt by the protocol, miners only get the gas premium.

This implementation has the objective to reduce the gas cost volatility in the long term.